# JSON parsing arrays from arrays (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist

I have a String which contains JSON File information.

```
    static String JSON_STRING2 ="{\"lex\": {\"seg\": [ [ 0, 8 ], [ 9, 5 ], [ 15, 6 ] ], \"s\": [ [ 0, 21 ] ], \"p\": [ [ 0, 21 ] ]}, \"morphology\": { \"msd\": [ [ [ \"red\", \"Agpmsnn\" ], [ \"red\", \"Agpfpan\" ], [ \"red\", \"Agpmsvn\" ] ], [ [ \"flower\", \"Ncfsgn-\" ], [ \"flower\", \"Ncfpnn-\" ], [ \"flower\", \"Ncfpvn-\" ] ], [ [ \"blossom\", \"Ncmsnn-\" ] ] ], \"stem\": [ \"rr\", \"ff\", \"bb\" ]}}";
```

What i want to do is to take this data ant save into arrays for further string comparision tasks, but at the moment i do not know how to reach bottom layer of "seg" layer and be able to take for example [0,8]  values by its position in array. As far as I get is taking whole Array element via get() . I tried looping data but most of the time i end up with wrong array or arrayList types.

My preview code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create root JSON Object
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING2);
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");

    // Get Data Values
    JSONObject LEX = object.getJSONObject("lex");

    System.out.println("------------- Data Values ---------------");

    System.out.println("Array Words : " + LEX.getJSONArray("seg").get(1));
    System.out.println("Array Sentences : " + LEX.getJSONArray("s"));
    System.out.println("Array Paragraphs : " + LEX.getJSONArray("p"));
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");

    // Get Data Values
    JSONObject MORP = object.getJSONObject("morphology");
    System.out.println("------------- Data Values ---------------");
    System.out.println("Array wordCharacteristic : " + MORP.getJSONArray("msd"));}
```

Any tips or tricks? I have read bounch of articles here non of them parsing familiar data to mine. Thanks.

Comment: Which json lib are you using ?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that `JSONArray` are 0-indexed, like the arrays and lists in java.
So `LEX.getJSONArray("seg").get(1)` return the **second** item in `seg`, thus printing `[9,5]`.

If you want the **first**, just use `LEX.getJSONArray("seg").get(0)`.

Now you can iterate on those JSONArray. There many ways to do that, here is one possibility:

```
    for (Object seg : LEX.getJSONArray("seg")) {
        JSONArray values = (JSONArray) seg;
        for (Object objValue : values) {
            int value = (int) objValue;
            System.out.print(value + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

will print this out:

```
0 8
9 5
15 6
```

Comment: Yes, I know about indexes .get(1) is just for exmample. Thank you for your solution but it throws inconvertible type error on line  int value = (int) objValue; 
So i'm still at the same point, cant read array [[0,8],[9,5],[15,6]] elements one by one

Comment: @MindaugasBauža This is really strange, because that method just work perfectly in my env, with the same sample you gave. Which type is returned by value, if not int ?

Comment: cannot cast 'java.lang.object' to 'int'

Comment: OK. Can you replace with System.out.print(objValue.getCass()); and tell me what it displays ?

Comment: Its output @Benoit

class java.lang.Integerclass java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Integerclass java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Integerclass java.lang.Integer

Comment: Found the problem @Benoit. Changed (int) to (Integer). Also adapted that method to morphology layer and added one more interaction.

One more thing can you give me advise on my problem. As you can see i have data of my words (position in sentence, lenght, sent. lenght and words morph info) Should i need to save this info into new arrays and then check if words is in the same sentence and can make collocations depending of their morph info or left it in arrayList? 'cause i still dont know how to use arraylist of arrays straight into my method then need to pick just specific values out of aray

Comment: Yes I think you should build your domain objects first, then trying to use them in a second phase.